# Multiple webmaster tools accounts on website

Tags: google-search-console

I've got a google webmasters tool account with a website I help look after, they've employed the services of an SEO/SEM company* who have asked to add google/microsoft/yahoo webmasters tools accounts

I don't want to give them access to my account (its tied in with other websites I have on webmasters tools) so my question is it ok/possible to have multiple webmaster tools accounts on a website?

*The company are trustworthy, they've been great to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. A site can have multiple owners. You don't need to give access to your account, each owner can have its own account and verify it against the site.

See [Multiple Users](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=44227&hl=en).

> A site can have more than one verified
>   owner, and you can add and remove
>   owners easily using the Manage
>   Verification page. (Note: To add a
>   person as a user, that person must
>   have a valid Google Account—for
>   example, a Gmail account.) These
>   owners will have all the same rights
>   as the original owner, including the
>   ability to add and remove owners.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple users for one Webmaster Tools account. The SEO company needs to have its own account, then add the site in question.

They will get a verification code or file - they can send this to you to add to the site. Now they will become verified owners and can see all the same stats you do.